# Operators overloading add using operator+ for a class-template

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, operator-overloading

I need a function to add values ​​to `v[i]` using the  `operator+`
the vector `v` contains the values `10,2` and `3`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Measurement 
{
private:
    T val;
public:
    Measurement(T a)
        : val{ a }
    {}

    T value() const { return val; }

    Measurement<T>& operator+(const T& nr) 
    {
        //... ???
        return *this;
    }

};

int main()
{
    //create a vector with values (10,2,3)
    std::vector<Measurement<int>> v{ 10,2,3 };
    v[2] + 3 + 2; //add at v[2] value 5
    for (const auto& m : v) std::cout << m.value() << ",";
    return 0;
}
```

The result must be `10,2,8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add the `val` of the instance to other `nr`

```
Measurement<T>& operator+(const T& nr)
{
   this->val += nr;
   return *this;
}
```

---

However, overloading the `operator+` for this might be misleading and should be avoiding such. Therefore I would suggest the traditional way

```
Measurement<T> operator+(const T& nr)
{
   Measurement<T> tmp{ *this };
   tmp.val += nr;
   return tmp;  // returns the temporary, which you need to reassign!
}
```

and do

```
v[2] = v[2] + 3 + 2;
```

for the required result.

---

Or even better provide `operator+=` which meant does return the reference to the `Measurement<T>`

```
Measurement<T>& operator+=(const T& nr)
{
   this->val += nr;
   return *this;
}
```

and call it like

```
v[2] += 3 + 2;
```

Comment: Although this is correct, I would be very confused by a `operator+` actually *modifying* the element and returning a *reference*.

Comment: @MikaelH Yeah. It is kind of misleading/ abusing the `operator+`!